# ¿Posicionamiento de header, footer y aside?

Tags: html, css

El código de css que tengo es el siguiente

```
header {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        background-color: #141616;
        z-index: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #383838;
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    body {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #1E2222;
        z-index: 0;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
    aside#left {
        width: 215px;
        background-color: #141616;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 999;
        border: 1px solid #383838;
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
    }
    footer {
        height: 42px;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: #141616;
        z-index: 1;
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    main{
        margin-left: 217px;
        margin-top: 61px;
    }
```

y mi html

```
<body>
<header></header>
<aside id="left">
    <img src="logo.png">
</aside>
<main style="background-color: red;">
asdf
</main>
<footer>Carinae Gaming</footer>
</body>
```

estoy buscando la manera en la que se represente como la siguiente figura:
[image]

En este caso el  sería el body ¿qué propiedades tengo que agregar?

Comment: Quizas sea mas sencillo usar una framwork de diseño boostrap o materialice http://materializecss.com/grid.html

Answer (score 1):

Que tal si intentas utilizando [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
A la hora de maquetar se hace mas fácil.

Pásate por la guía de [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Espero te resulte útil.

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.wrapper{
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: #000;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 90%;
}

header {
  background: coral;
  height: 5em;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 10em;
}

aside {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 30%;
}

section {
  background: lightblue;
  width: 70%;
}

footer {
  background: lightgray;
  height: 5em;
  width: 100%;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="center">
    <span>Header</span>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <aside class="center">
      <span>Aside</span>
    </aside>
    <section class="center">
      <span>Body</span>
    </section>
  </div>
  <footer class="center">
    <span>Footer</span>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal sería usar Flexbox, te ahorrarías un motón de tiempo.

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <header>Header</header>
   <div class="container">
     <aside>Aside</aside>
     <section class="body">Body</section>  
   </div>
   <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

body > * {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

body > *:last-child {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

header,
footer {
  min-height: 100px;
}

aside {
  width: 25%;
  border: 0 solid #000;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.container .body {
  width: 75%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una excelente opción para maquetar es utilizar bootstrap, ahorras tiempo y los sitios son responsivos, y tiene implementados un montón de cosas que solo sería copiar y pegar, espero te sea de ayuda.

Aquí te dejo como quedaría utilizando bootstrap, solo quedaría agregarle los css a su conveniencia.

```
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Titulo de la web</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script Language=Javascript src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="alternate" title="Pozolería RSS" type="application/rss+xml" href="/feed.rss" />
</head>

<body>
    <header>
       <h1>Mi sitio web</h1>
       <p>Mi sitio web creado en html5</p>
    </header>
    <section class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <aside class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
                <h3>Titulo de contenido</h3>
                <p>contenido</p>
            </aside>
            <article class="col-xs-12 col-md-9">
                <h2>Titilo de contenido<h2>
                <p>Contenido (ademas de imagenes, citas, videos etc.)</p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>
        Creado por mi el 2011
    </footer>
</body>
```